# JMS Not working in Wso2Esb 4.7.0

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am working with wso2esb 4.7.0 and ActiveMQ5.8.0 whenever i am working with wso2esb4.6.0 and ActiveMQ5.5.1 its working fine i am publishing my configuration below any one help for this
message store

```
 <messageStore xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                  class="org.wso2.carbon.message.store.persistence.jms.JMSMessageStore"
                  name="JMSQueue">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="store.jms.cache.connection">false</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
       <parameter name="store.jms.JMSSpecVersion">1.1</parameter>
       <parameter name="store.jms.destination">JMS_Reading_Queue</parameter>
    </messageStore>
```

message processor

```
<messageProcessor xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                  class="org.apache.synapse.message.processors.forward.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor"
                  name="faisal"
                  messageStore="JMSQueue">
   <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
   <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
</messageProcessor
```

and proxy is like this

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Jms"
       transports="https http jms"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <store messageStore="JMSQueue"/>
         <property name="target.endpoint"
                   value="JmsEndpoint"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

and i defined my endpoint in endpoints

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="JmsEndpoint">
   <address uri="http://192.168.1.122:8282/services/ReadingsMobile"
            format="soap11"/>
</endpoint>
```

now i am getting no target endpoint errors same configuration working in wso2esb4.6.0 mbut not working in wso2esb4.7.0
and its giving errors like this

```
[2013-08-21 16:48:32,049]  WARN - ForwardingHandler Property target.endpoint not found in the message context. Removing the message.
[2013-08-21 16:49:32,093]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-13
```

Comment: every time message going into dequeue mode in activemq UI

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the below modifications in the proxy configuration in order to get rid of the warnings;

a) Replace < target > with < target endpoint="JmsEndpoint" >

b) Move the "store" tag entry after the property where you set the "target.endpoint".

These changes seem to do the trick in my environment. Check if it fixes your issue too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error you are getting says message processor cannot find the target.endpoint property from the stored message context.

The reason for this is, you are storing the message before setting this property.

You have to set the 'target.endpoint' property before the store mediator in the flow.

Proxy configuration should look likes follows.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="Jms"
   transports="https http jms"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
   <inSequence>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property name="target.endpoint"
               value="JmsEndpoint"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
     <store messageStore="JMSQueue"/>
   </inSequence>
   <outSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```